# slf4j does not find log4j2 jars

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, slf4j

I know it should be easy to use [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) with Log4j2 as logger implementation.

> You just need to add the jars to the classpath.

I have thought that I did so, but I am still getting

```
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

The crucial parts of my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j18-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then an excerpt from `.classpath`

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30-sources.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j18-impl/2.14.0/log4j-slf4j18-impl-2.14.0.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j18-impl/2.14.0/log4j-slf4j18-impl-2.14.0-sources.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.14.0/log4j-api-2.14.0.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.14.0/log4j-api-2.14.0-sources.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.14.0/log4j-core-2.14.0.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.14.0/log4j-core-2.14.0-sources.jar"/>
```

Then, looking in the *lib* folder

```
$ find ./ -name "*slf4*.jar"
./target/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j18-impl-2.14.0.jar
./target/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar

$ find ./ -name "*log4j*.jar"
./target/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j18-impl-2.14.0.jar
./target/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.14.0.jar
./target/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.14.0.jar
```

#### What am I missing?

Do I need to add a log4j2 [config xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30670939/2092322)?

But I do not get the [corresponding error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52300045/initialize-slf4j-with-log4j2-xml).

I am using

- Eclipse Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
- Apache Maven 3.6.3

And the `maven-war-plugin`

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33390519/2092322 annotations instead of web.xml -->
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using `slf4j 1.7.*` but you using `logj4j-slf4j18-impl` which suppose to be used with slf4j 1.8 (which doesn't released yet or change to version 2.0.0 which currently in alpha version).
You need to change from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j18-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

in order to make it compatible with slf4j that you used in your project

Comment: Oh, stupid me! I did not pay attention to the versions. Now I don't get the error messages anymore, but also no logs. I think I need to add some configuration.

Comment: The interesting part for my current problem is as follows: For me it's only logging if I use the log4-slf4j18-impl library together with slf4j-api:1.7.30; Why? Any suggestions where I can look that interfers with 1.7.3 or similar? I mean it's completely the different way as documentation is suggesting.

Comment: @MarkusG. do you have multiple version of slf4j-api as your projects dependencies?

Comment: only 1.7.25 but it looks like it is rematches to 1.7.30 Versions: "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30"