# No logs of servlets in Eclipse starting Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, logging, slf4j

I am using

- Tomcat 9
- Eclipse Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
- Apache Maven 3.6.3

and I am starting to write a servlet, which runs in the Tomcat container. When I run it in Ecplise (*Debug on Server*) I can see some logging output from Tomcat. Like

```
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 08, 2020 4:21:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
Dec 08, 2020 4:21:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [1291] milliseconds
Dec 08, 2020 4:21:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Dec 08, 2020 4:21:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
Dec 08, 2020 4:21:36 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Dec 08, 2020 4:21:38 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.WadlFeature configure
WARNING: JAXBContext implementation could not be found. WADL feature is disabled.
Dec 08, 2020 4:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [/home/myname/bin/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.39/webapps/examples]
Dec 08, 2020 4:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Dec 08, 2020 4:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()

... ...
```

The servlet runs fine and the start looks like this:

```
public class MyMain extends Application {
    
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SdpApiMain.class);
    
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(Test.class);
        s.add(User.class);
        logger.debug("We are in main class, collectiong resources.");
        return s;
    }
}
```

But I do not see the *debug line*.

For logging I am using [slf4j 1.7 and log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65189454/slf4j-does-not-find-log4j2-jars). I have the following `log4j2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Do I just need a different console view in Eclipse? Anything wrong with my configuration and how can I debug it?

Comment: Does this logging setup work in a standalone Java application?

Comment: I did not test it and for now the whole setup seems to be very outdated to me. I'll keep checking it.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps for a solution for this problem:

We are talking about Eclipse, so I have added the `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` flag to

*Run Configurations -> Arguments (tab)*

Then I could see that log4j2 needs the `log4j2-web` dependency in this setup. And it complained that it could not see a configuration file, so I added the `log4j2.xml` the right place (in the classpath). (Eclipse: *right click on src/main/resources -> new 'other' -> xml file*.) This folder was already in my classpath, the formerly used one not.

When there is no configuration file it uses it sdt configuration, which has log level *error* as default.